# How to make a get all records using pageable in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I am trying to get all records from a h2 database using pageable. I can pull the results using normal findAll(), but when I try using pageable, I am not able to

This is my controller

```
@GetMapping
Page<PostInfo> getPosts(Pageable pageable) {
    return postService.getPosts(pageable);
}
```

this are my models
My Post model

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

My Postdetails class which extends postinfo

```
@Data
@ToString
public class PostDetails extends PostInfo {
    private String content;
}
```

My Postinfo class

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
public class PostInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

My PostService service class

```
public interface PostService {

    PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest createPostRequest);

    Page<PostInfo>getPosts(final Pageable pageable);

    PostDetails getPostDetails(Long id);

    void deletePost(Long id);
}
```

My Implementation class

```
 @Override
    public Page<PostInfo> getPosts(Pageable pageable) {
       return postRepository.findAll(pageable);

    }
```

I end up getting not getting pageable data. How can I use pageable to findAll() records stored. I have researched with no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be worth having a read about how to implement and use Pagination: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: Hi @Oozeerally I have gone through the link shared but no luck yet. The Repository extends JPARepository.

Answer (score 0):

Use PageRequest.of(pageNumber,pageSize) in your implementation, like:

```
@Override
public Page<PostInfo> getPosts(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
   return postRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber,pageSize));

}
```

and in your interface use:

```
Page<PostInfo> getPosts(int pageNumber, int pageSize);
```

instead of:

```
Page<PostInfo>getPosts(final Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).